# How to get this jsfiddle example to work?

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle

I have been trying to get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/wJ5ey/) jsfiddle to work. So far without luck.

The html I have written(copied) as this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <!-- add some head tags here -->

  <title>Try</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "http://rniemeyer.github.com/KnockMeOut/Scripts/knockout-latest.debug.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/knockout.mapping.js">
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  body, a, p { font-size: .85em; }
  input { width: 100px; }
  table { border: 1px solid black; }
  h3, p, td, th { padding: 3px; }
  h3 { font-weight: bold; }
  .matched { background-color: yellow; }
  .n { text-align: right; }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/array_mapping.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.min.js">
</script>

  <h3>1- JSON string from server</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: JSONdataFromServer"></p>

  <h3>2- Converted to an object with ko.parseJSON</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(dataFromServer)"></p>

  <h3>3- Mapped to use observables and add a dependentObservable</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(mappedData)"></p>
  <hr />

  <h3>4- Display in an editor</h3><script id="itemsTmpl" type="text/html">
<![CDATA[
        <tr data-bind="css: { matched: $data === viewModel.firstMatch() }">
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: viewModel.categories, value: category"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="n" data-bind="value: price" />
            </td>
            <td class="n" data-bind="text: priceWithTax">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeItem($data); }">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
  ]]>
  </script>

  <table id="mytable" data-bind="triggerUpdate: items">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Category</th>

        <th>Price</th>

        <th>w/Tax</th>

        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:%20void(0);" data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</a></td>

      <td></td>

      <td class="n">Total:</td>

      <td class="n" data-bind="text: total"></td>

      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h3>5- Filter display by name</h3>

  <p>Filter: <input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>

  <h3>6- Find first match by name</h3>

  <p>Search: <input data-bind="value: search, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
  <hr />

  <h3>7- Use ko.utils.arrayMap to build an array with just categories used</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.justCategories)"></p>

  <h3>8- Use ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues to get just the unique categories used</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.uniqueCategories)"></p>

  <h3>9- Use ko.utils.compareArrays to find available categories that haven't been
  used</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.missingCategories)"></p>

  <h3>10- Convert items to JSON</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.items)"></p>

  <h3>11- Map items to send back to server and convert to JSON</h3>

  <p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel.mappedItems)"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And javascript is in a file called array_mapping.js and looks like this

```
    function Item(name, category, price) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.category = ko.observable(category);
        this.price = ko.observable(price);
        this.priceWithTax = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
            return (this.price() * 1.05).toFixed(2);
        }, this);
    }

    var viewModel = {
        categories: ["Bread", "Dairy", "Fruits", "Vegetables"],
        items: ko.observableArray([]),
        filter: ko.observable(""),
        search: ko.observable(""),
        addItem: function() {
            this.items.push(new Item("New", "", 1));
        },
        removeItem: function(item) {
            this.items.remove(item);
        }
    };

    //ko.utils.arrayFilter - filter the items using the filter text
    viewModel.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return this.items();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
                return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), filter);
            });
        }
    }, viewModel);


    //ko.utils.arrayForEach - return a total by adding all prices
    viewModel.total = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.filteredItems(), function(item) {
            var value = parseFloat(item.priceWithTax());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
            }
        });
        return total.toFixed(2);
    }, viewModel);


    //ko.utils.arrayFirst - identify the first matching item by name
    viewModel.firstMatch = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var search = this.search().toLowerCase();
        if (!search) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.filteredItems(), function(item) {
                return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), search);
            });
        }
    }, viewModel);

    //ko.utils.arrayMap - get a list of used categories
    viewModel.justCategories = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var categories = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.category();
        });
        return categories.sort();
    }, viewModel);

    //ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues - get a unique list of used categories
    viewModel.uniqueCategories = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(viewModel.justCategories()).sort();
    }, viewModel);

    //ko.utils.compareArrays - find any unused categories
    viewModel.missingCategories = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        //find out the categories that are missing from uniqueNames
        var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(viewModel.categories, viewModel.uniqueCategories());
        //return a flat list of differences
        var results = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function(difference) {
            if (difference.status === "deleted") {
                results.push(difference.value);
            }
        });
        return results;
    }, viewModel);

    //ko.utils.arrayMap - prepare items to be sent back to server
    viewModel.mappedItems = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var items = ko.toJS(this.items);
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(item) {
            delete item.priceWithTax;
            return item;
        });
    }, viewModel);

    //a JSON string that we got from the server that wasn't automatically converted to an object
    var JSONdataFromServer = '[{"name":"Peach","category":"Fruits","price":1},{"name":"Plum","category":"Fruits","price":0.75},{"name":"Donut","category":"Bread","price":1.5},{"name":"Milk","category":"Dairy","price":4.50}]';

    //parse into an object
    var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

    //do some basic mapping (without mapping plugin)
    var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataFromServer, function(item) {
        return new Item(item.name, item.category, item.price);
    });

    viewModel.items(mappedData);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

All the links in script part are working. But I am not able to get the desired result.

I have noticed that if I try anything other option on the framework menu(for example onLoad), the code does not run on jsfiddle either. Could it be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the bindings in the HTML that refer to `viewModel` are using it as a global variable. So, when you do `onLoad` it will not be global.  With KO 2.0, you can now replace `viewModel` with `$root` and `viewModel` would not need to be global.  I would grab an updated version of KO from: https://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js

Also, any code that calls `ko.applyBindings` should be put at the bottom of the page or in something like the jQuery "ready" function, as it needs the DOM to be complete.  So, you could put your external js file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I tried putting the <script> link at the bottom of the page and enclosed it within $(function(){...});, I grabbed the new version of knockout as well. Even then, I am not getting any results on the page. i am using pyramid web framework to deliver the files. BTW thanks for the help. I am very happy that you are the author of the site I am referring to as well :)

Comment: Maybe send me an email with the current output of the HTML that you are trying to display.  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I put the script first time after </head> tag. Then I put it just before </body>.  Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.